# Symfony2 - Entity findAll return large response on API

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine

I have an API developed in Symfony2 but when i send a request to it the response returns with 204Mb for only 40 rows... This is the code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$themes = $em->getRepository("KlickpagesAdminBundle:Theme")->findAll();
return $themes;
```

Im use FOSRestBundle to serialize and returns the json.

How i can resolve this?

Comment: Does your theme entity have relations to other entities which in turn might be related to still more entities?  A straight forward serialize might end up loading the entire database thanks to lazy loading.  You might also want to verify that there is no cross linking between the same entities.  You could be getting into a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aa @Cerad said it is very like because of relations to other entities and lazy loading going in circles

For a quick test exclude all fields from the serilazition, except few scalar ones like so:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;

/**
 * Group
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Group implements GroupInterface
{
    /**
     * @Expose
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Expose
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Relation to privilegesis not explicitly exposed.
     * @var Privilege[]
     */
    private $privileges;

    /**
     * Relation to Users not explicitly exposed.

     * @var User[]
     */
    private $users;
    ...
```

The important parts are exclusionStrategy and expose antations.

If this will help, you got for sure a circles serialization of your annotations and the right solution is to define serialization groups, lets say like this:

```
     /**
     * @Expose
     * @Groups({"groupDetail", "userAuthenticate"})
     *
     * @var Privilege[]
     */
    private $privileges;

    /**
     * @Expose
     * @Groups({"groupDetail"})
     *
     * @var User[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $users;
```

You can then define by which group should be the response serialized on your controller or programatically.

```
 // controllerAction

     /*
     * @Annotations\View(serializerGroups={"Default","groupDetail"})
     */
     public function getGroupAction($groupId) { ... }

// programatically

    ...
    /** @var $context SerializationContext */
    $context             = SerializationContext::create();
    $serializationGroups = ['Default', 'GroupDetail'];
    $context->setGroups($serializationGroups);
    $view = $this->view($collection, 200);
    $view->setSerializationContext($context);

    return $this->handleView($view);
    ...
```

Resources: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies